# Space efficient conversion from Wrapper to primitive and primitive to Wrapper

Tags: java, performance, memory-efficient

Given the following function:

```
public void convertToWrapper(long[] longsToConvert)  
{    

}
```

and

```
public void convertToPrimitive(Long[] longsToConvert)  
{  
}
```

[Apache ArrayUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html#toObject%28long%5B%5D%29) exposes the following:

```
public Long[] toObject(long[] longs){
    final Long [] result = new Long [array.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
             result[i] = new Long (array[i]);
         }
}
```

My question is there a way to do this utilizing only one array?  I have tried the following which does not work:

```
for(int i =0;i<array.length;i++)  
{  
     array[i] = new Long(array[i]);
}
```

Comment: I don;t think it is possible.

Comment: Note that it would probably be more efficient to write: `array[i] = Long.valueOf(array[i]);` instead of `array[i] = new Long(array[i]);` as `Longs` are generally cached between -128 and +127 (even if it is not required by the JLS).

Comment: Please note that Long.valueOf was added in 1.5, which I guess explains the ArrayUtils code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  A `Long[]` is not the same type as a `long[]`, so assignment will fail.

Comment: I understand that, however, I was under the impression that I could unwrap the Wrapper.  Similar to what auto-boxing does.

Comment: Yes, you can unwrap the wrapper.  But a `Long[]` is first and foremost an `array`, and a `Long` second.